# adwords ads shows for one word keyword but i have only two word keywords

Tags: google-ads-api

I have they keywords in google adwords
foam puzzle
kids puzzle
toys puzzle

but my ad shows when you type only one word keyword "puzzle"

why ? 
how can i force showing me ads only for these three two-word keywords ?

Thanks

Comment: This is off-topic because it's about Ad words administration, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

You need to investigate the keyword *Match Types* on offer - broadly speaking we have:

- An **exact** match keyword matches exactly the string you use (more or
  less - there are still some close variants, & depending on campaign
  settings, plurals)

  A **Phrase** match matches any string containing your keyword - for
  example: `red kids puzzle`

  A **broad** match matches "similar" things to your keywords  (you can
  also "modify" this match type by preppending `+` to words in your keywords but
  I'll leave you to research that yoourself).

More info:

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2497836?hl=en